# Best way to concatenate objects into a single string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, casting, type-conversion

```
string resultString = dtMRow("mcode") + "_" + dtRow("pcode")
```

When I execute the above code I am expecting `resultString` to be assigned to something like `"2356_ASDKJ"`, but instead I get the following exception:

> Conversion from string "_" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Why is the compiler trying to cast the `"_"` into a `Double`?

What is the easiest way to get it to cast everything into `strings`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `dtMRow("mcode")` and `dtRow("pcode")`?

Comment: Very strange - it should have compiled... ([link](http://ideone.com/tcoAOX)).

Answer (score 7):

because dtMRow returns double?

best way will be

```
String.Format("{0}_{1}", dtMRow("mcode"), dtRow("pcode"));
```

Comment: nice, sorry for previous comment, didn't realise that [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) will return the string representation of an object - @DominicKexel

Comment: @Herdo, you can't edit answer to add your own thoughts. Create your own answer if you think this doesn't fully answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
string resultString = string.format("{0}_{1}", dtMRow("mcode").ToString(), dtRow("pcode").ToString());
```

I would use `ToString()` to avoid boxing operations.

Comment: IMO, the .ToString() version is less readable and isn't worth the saving of any cost of boxing operations.

Comment: What are "boxing operations"?

Answer (score 1):

best performance:

```
string resultString = dtMRow("mcode").ToString() + "_" + dtRow("pcode").ToString();
```

equal:

```
string resultString = string.Concat(dtMRow("mcode").ToString(), "_", dtRow("pcode").ToString());
```

best view but worst performance:

```
string resultString = string.format("{0}_{1}", dtMRow("mcode").ToString(), dtRow("pcode").ToString());
```

worst view and worst performance: stringBuilder for few object

p.s.: `.ToString()` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the compiler trying to cast the "_" into a Double?

Because the types in `dtMRow("mcode")` are probably `doubles`.

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) will covert them to a string for you:

```
string result = string.Format("{0}_{1}", dtMRow("mcode"), dtRow("pcode"));
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use an instance of System.Text.StringBuilder instead of string. And in your case, use ToString() to explicitly convert whatever comes to string:

```
dtMRow("mcode").ToString() + "_" + dtRow("pcode").ToString()
```